# Iterate through cursor and storing the output of the cursor in another table

Tags: for-loop, plsql, cursor

I am trying to iterate through a cursor which stores the value of the table. I use a FOR Loop to iterate and IF one of the conditions is met, I store the output in another table. I am not sure of the approach I am following and also getting error(ORA-00933: SQL command not ended properly). Stats_Queries is my reference table where I iterate my cursor through. STATS_RESULT_CARD is my output table where I have to store the results. Please help.

```
 DECLARE
     CURSOR c1 IS
       select Stats_Queries.OBJECTTYPE, Stats_Queries.CATEGORY, Stats_Queries.QUERY  
       from Stats_Queries;
    r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
      FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
        If (r1.OBJECTTYPE = 'CARD') THEN
        INSERT INTO STATS_RESULTS_CARD (NODETYPENAME, NODEDEFNAME , CARDTYPENAME, PROVISIONSTATUSNAME, STATDATE, CARDCOUNT)
        select nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name, sysdate, count(c.cardid)
    from cardtype ct, card c, node n, nodetype nt, nodedef nd, provisionstatus ps
    where ct.name in ('SRA AMP', 'XLA AMP', 'SAM', 'ESAM')
    and ct.cardtypeid = c.card2cardtype
    and c.card2node = n.nodeid
    and n.node2nodetype = nt.nodetypeid
    and n.node2nodedef = nd.nodedefid
    and c.card2provisionstatus = ps.provisionstatusid
    group by nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name
    END If;
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: You don't have any link between the cursor and the insert statement inside the loop. Therefore, you are inserting X copies of the same data depending on how many rows in your cursor have an objecttype of 'CARD' (as an aside, why are you doing that filter in the loop and not in the cursor itself?!). Is that what you wanted to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside from the answer that Finbarr has provided (which is perfectly correct; add in the missing semi-colon and your procedure should work), why do you need to loop through the cursor at all? That's the slow way of doing it.

You could just do a single insert statement instead, such as:

```
  insert into stats_results_card (nodetypename,
                                  nodedefname,
                                  cardtypename,
                                  provisionstatusname,
                                  statdate,
                                  cardcount)
    select x.nt_name,
           x.nd_name,
           x.ct_name,
           x.ps_name,
           x.statdate,
           x.cnt_cardid                               
    from   (select   nt.name nt_name,
                     nd.name nd_name,
                     ct.name ct_name,
                     ps.name ps_name,
                     sysdate statdate,
                     count (c.cardid) cnt_cardid
            from     cardtype ct,
                     card c,
                     node n,
                     nodetype nt,
                     nodedef nd,
                     provisionstatus ps
            where        ct.name in ('SRA AMP',
                                     'XLA AMP',
                                     'SAM',
                                     'ESAM')
                     and ct.cardtypeid = c.card2cardtype
                     and c.card2node = n.nodeid
                     and n.node2nodetype = nt.nodetypeid
                     and n.node2nodedef = nd.nodedefid
                     and c.card2provisionstatus = ps.provisionstatusid
            group by nt.name,
                     nd.name,
                     ct.name,
                     ps.name) x
           cross join (select stats_queries.objecttype,
                              stats_queries.category,
                              stats_queries.query
                       from   stats_queries
                       where  objecttype = 'CARD');
```

N.B. This assumes that there really isn't any link between the original cursor and the select statement that was inside the loop; we do a cross join to replicate the rows the required number of times.

If there was an actual join between the two queries, you would put that in place of the cross join.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not ended properly
```

Probably occurring because you missed a semicolon after

```
group by nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name
```